# Как получить свойство конструктора через метод с таймаутом?

Tags: javascript, конструктор

```js
function catTemplate(cat) {
  this.word = 'meow',
    this.voice = function() {
      return console.log(this.word);
    };
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```

### Нормально работает, выводит meow

```js
function catTemplate(cat) {
  this.word = 'meow',
    this.voice = setTimeout(function() {
      return console.log(this.word);
    }, 1000);
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```

### С таймаутом выводит not a function

Хотелось бы получить свойство именно через Barsik.voice()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function catTemplate(cat) {
  this.word = 'meow',
  this.voice = () => setTimeout(() => console.log(this.word), 1000);
}
var Barsik = new catTemplate;
Barsik.voice();
```